# TypeError: first.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, regex, string, properties, typeerror

I tried running this code and I can not understand why the error 'TypeError: first.value is undefined', should arise in my use-case highlighted below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "aust988957588raliajfur748jejfu3737238ef8re8e";
  var res = str.split("");

  var first = res[0];
  var a = /^[a]$/;

  if (first.value.match(a)) {
    alert("a");
  } else {
    alert("false");
  }
}
```

A careful review of this reosource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_type did not help.

What is the issue causing this error?

Comment: That's means `first` doesn't have a `value` property. Where should it be given one?

Comment: It's because `first.value` is `undefined`...sound familiar?

Comment: who voted my question down. I hope it makes him sleep better at night?

Answer (score 2):

`first` would be string `"a"`, a string doesn't have `value` property, so it returns `undefined`. Use just `first.match(a)`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "aust988957588raliajfur748jejfu3737238ef8re8e";
  var res = str.split("");

  var first = res[0];
  var a = /^[a]$/;

  if (first.match(a)) {
    alert("a");
  } else {
    alert("false");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object doesn't have the property `value`.

So you can fix it by changing `if(first.value.match(a))` to `if(first.match(a))`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "aust988957588raliajfur748jejfu3737238ef8re8e";
  var res = str.split("");
  var first =  res[0];  
  var a = /^[a]$/; 
  if(first.match(a))   
  {   
    alert("a");
  }  
  else  
  {   
    alert("false");
  }   
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: @Andy Because the string object does not have a property `value`.

Comment: Why didn't you include that in your answer then?

Answer (score 0):

try just doing:

```
first.match(a)
```

see if that works

Comment: because its a pure string, you don't need the value method (and it won't work...)

Comment: Why didn't you include that in your answer then? If your answer is more complete you'll get more upvotes. As it stands this isn't a great answer.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to implement this comment in my next answers

Comment: No need to apologise. I'm just offering advice to help you write better answers. Sometimes not being the first to answer to get points can be advantageous :)